# Icons are stretched after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, icons, search

I upgraded to 20.04 earlier. One problem I couldn't find information about is that when large icons are used (Application and search), the icons are stretched - they appear too tall and overlap with other controls:

[image]

I looked for relevant configuration and couldn't find it, and tried other icon themes which all did the same.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's a themeing part. Change gnome-shell theme to default and feel the difference. To fix it, need to go through the theme that is expanding it or contact theme developer.

Comment: @UnKNOWn - that was it, thanks! I actually tried installing a new theme (upgraded the Yaru theme), and only my favorite color has this bug.